# Cascaded system, deconvolution , IIR filter

Tags: signals

Cascaded system, Please, look at the picture? Could you explain f?
I am also including solution. I did not get why H1(z)=y1[n] which is 1+5/6z^-1

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like there's something wrong with the typesetting of the question. It says "y1[n] = x[n]+™x[n-1]", which doesn't make any sense. But if you replace ™ with 5/6, then it's the same y1 as in the previous exercises, and the transfer function agrees with the solution.